# how and when -EINTR is set when linux system call is blocked

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, signals, system-calls

If a system call is blocked , the process state is set to `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`, and the process is removed from run queue.
When a signal is delivered to that process, kernel adds the signal to list of pending signals and sets the process state to `TASK_RUNNING`.
And when next time `schedule()` is called this process is executed.
What i did not understand is how exactly blocked system call returns `-EINTR` to userspace?
Any blocked system call can return `-EINTR`?
The logic of setting `-EINTR` is done by signal handling code or by system call itself?
AFAIK signal handling only happens before returning to userspace, is that true?
Does signal handling happens during context switch?
Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 1):

When the process is running again (i.e., when `schedule()` returns), the driver must check for this case with the `signal_pending()` function, and abort what it's doing and return the `-EINTR` error code.

Many system calls are *restartable*, i.e., after interrupted by a signal, they could be just executed again without changing the functionality.
In that case, they return `-ERESTARTSYS` instead of `-EINTR`, and the kernel will handle the restarting automatically after the signal has been handled.

For an example, see the function `uart_wait_modem_status` in `drivers/tty/serial/serial_core.c`, or any other place where [EINTR](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=EINTR) or [ERESTARTSYS](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=ERESTARTSYS) are used.